# HiveServer2 Authentication: HTTP ERROR CODE 401

Tags: authentication, hadoop, hive, http-status-code-401, hdp

Recently we have deployed LDAP Authentication on HiveServe2 in our HDP Production Cluster.

Many users are complaining that they are receiving below error randomly:

**[Code: 0, SQL State: 08S01]  org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: HTTP Response code: 401**

Can anyone give me a hint on how to resolve it? We don't have Knox or Kerberos setup.

I have gone through the logs and this issue seems to be temporary but annoying. If we try to re-run the code a few times, it will eventually run successfully.

Comment: With HTTP transport, could be related to a problem with session cookies that are valid against **one** instance. In case of failover -- or in case of restart -- the cookie is (unexpectedly) invalid and triggers weird error messages... Until its end-of-life is reached.

Comment: I usually see cookies error in hiveserver2 logs. attaching 2 lines error below. Let me know if it gives you some hint
INFO  [HiveServer2-HttpHandler-Pool: Thread-285278]: thrift.ThriftHttpServlet (ThriftHttpServlet.java:doPost(145)) - Could not validate cookie sent, will try to generate a new cookie

2019-12-19 18:12:19,857 INFO  [HiveServer2-HttpHandler-Pool: Thread-285278]: auth.LdapAuthenticationProviderImpl (LdapAuthenticationProviderImpl.java:Authenticate(279)) - Authentication succeeded using ldap user search

Comment: Not really, I was referring to the behavior described in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KNOX-1196 but the root cause was (in older versions at least) the weird error code 500; here error code 401 is explicitly about auth.